# Magento Performance: How to use several subdomains (static1-3) for static assets?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

is there an easy way to add subdomains to the URLs of my static assets (JS, CSS, images) in Magento? What I am looking for is a way to change an url like this

```
http://store.com/js/script.js
```

to this

```
http://static1.store.com/js/script.js
```

The number behind 'static' should be rand(1,3).

The reason I want that is of course performance. By spreading assets over several domains browsers load them faster since they are restricted to load not more than 2 files from one domain at a time.

I know there exists [a plugin for Wordpress](https://github.com/wmark/CDN-Linker) and I would like to do it for Magento.

This whole thing has to happen server side, so before any html is generated.

Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

To speed up static content the best way is using a good CDN.

I'm using AWS CloudFront (http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/).

Using CloudFront you don't need to worry about http requests in several subdomains, the CDN deals with it for you.